# how to edit permission of liferay guest and site member from mysql databse?

Tags: mysql, permissions, liferay, liferay-6

While Using liferay hosted on my local server by mistake i have just unchecked the permission of guest and site member to view the welcome page from my admin account .now i cant access any pages and even its doesn't allow me to sign in either .i have checked the database of my life ray portal but i couldn't find out the solution.any one can guide me that which table and which permission i need to edit in MySQL database .i am new bee so i don't know about this.
i have seen user_role and user permission table but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Try login with the URL `http://localhost:8080/c/portal/login`, see it this helps.

Comment: thanks for reply.but i had just deleted my database and by that way i solved my issue

Comment: :-D Nice. Very nice way indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE public.resourcepermission SET actionids = 15 WHERE roleid = (select roleid FROM public.role_ WHERE name = 'Guest')
```

Comment: I had the same problem, changed that table, but only where my primkey recordd was the plid of my welcome layout. But I have a question, why 15, 1 is the view permission for every resources, including layouts.

Comment: This worked for me:
UPDATE ResourcePermission SET actionids = 15 
WHERE roleid = (select roleid FROM Role_ WHERE name = 'Guest')
AND primKey IN (select plid from Layout where name like '%welcome%')